# Display Image from URL in table view rows

Tags: swift, image, tableview

I'm setting a new app for displaying movies on a list of rows in table view, but the image wont to display

i have a model for movie that has the name and image url as a strings 
also i have a list of all movies that contains a few movies

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let allMovies = Movies()

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return(allMovies.list.count)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: allMovies.list[indexPath.row].imageURL)
        cell.textLabel?.text = allMovies.list[indexPath.row].name
        return(cell)
    }
```

Comment: Is the image URL to a local file? Have you verified the path?

Comment: No it isn’t in local file, its in a URL as as string

Comment: `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` only works with local file paths, not remote URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentsOfFile`   functionality is fit for local urls

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: allMovies.list[indexPath.row].imageURL)
```

so either ( totally not recommended )

```
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf:URL(string: allMovies.list[indexPath.row].imageURL)!) { // not recommended 
   cell.imageView?.image =  UIImage(data:data)
}
```

OR It's better to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

Comment: Oh i see , it works great but could you tell me why wouldn’t you recommend it?

Comment: as it blocks the main thread and re-downloads the image again if you scrolled without a cache